# Should I, as an amateur, get my result published based on a well known professor's opinion?

Tags: publications, mathematics, independent-researcher

I don't have any formal education in mathematics that the large part of mathematicians have but fortunately I have the ability to use intuition to obtain results in higher mathematics that many professional mathematicians find interesting.

So recently I happened to send this famous professor (whom I've been corresponding with for some time) one of my results and he responded by saying that "indeed he thinks the result is new"

So what's the next step? Should I try to get the result published?

Comment: Do you think that the rest of the message was encouraging? One can write "meh - this result is new, but I am not thrilled; probably it has very little use", or "this result is new; I find it very interesting, you should definitely try to publish it".

Comment: I am quite puzzled that you, after conversing with this "famous professor" about your research already, come to this forum to ask whether you should publish it rather than asking her/him. So much so, in fact, that I suspect that you are not telling us the full story here.

Comment: In addition to being able to give a more informed reading on whether to try to publish, the famous professor should be able to advise on a choice of journal.

Comment: Did "the famous professor" check the proof? If the result is new and the proof is correct, I see no reason not to try to publish (where exactly to publish is another question). If you communicated the result only, I will be way more skeptical: after all, anybody can announce any wonderful result he wants at any time (not necessarily intentionally cheating; honest mistakes happen way more often than people think they should).

Comment: The next step is to reply to the famous professor: "Thanks for your encouragement. What's the next step?"

Comment: I've often wondered what I'd do in such a situation. To be honest, I think you should make a YouTube video presenting your result. That way, people will know that you did it. They will also know when you did it. You'll have name and face recognition for your accomplishment.

Comment: Well, the result may be new, but unless you have a proof, it is a conjecture only. This is valid, but you should get together with a professional in the field (e.g. this professor, if he is interested) to bring this to a closure. However, you didn't - so, why not?

Comment: @Inquisitive Posting a Youtube video appears to me to be the least effective way possible to disseminate a new mathematical result. Widely worse than submitting a paper or posting to arXiv, likely even worse than posting it to Facebook or on LinkedIn, and on about the same level of effectiveness as shouting your proof from a barrel at your town square.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming* the following premises are true:

- The professor you state is well-known and established in his field
- You have produced a tangible result in this field
- The professor endorses your result to be new

Then,

> Get the result published!

I do not see any reason for this not to be published. Better yet, contact the professor for further directions (see comments).